# Calling child_process with Node.js vs calling child process from C and creating a C++ bind to call from node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js

I would like to call pdftotext to extract the content of 100.000 files (and i need to be fast), so, which of these two implementations would be the fastest?

Implementation 1:

Create a child_process from node.js, for every extraction:

```
export default (file) => new Promise((resove, reject) => {
  const command = 'pdftotext'
  const args = ['-layout', '-enc', 'UTF-8', file, '-']
  const process = spawn(command, args)
  const stdout = []
  const stderr = []

  process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    stdout.push(data)
  })

  process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    stderr.push(data)
  })

  process.on('error', (error) => {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT')
      error.message = 'pdftotext is not installed, so will be unable to extract the file content'
    reject(error)
  })

  process.on('close', () => {
    if (stderr.length)
      return reject(stderr.map(Error))
    resolve(stdout.join())
  })
}
```

Implementation 2:

Create a child_process from C, and create a C++ binding to call from node.js

-- Without code because I'm still learning how to do it --

Comment: Is it an alternative to convert the files once, e.g. using a command-line command?

Comment: Not really, i need this like a lib, i need import in my main module to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely process invocation code will have nonessential impact on performance and the speed of document processing depends on pdftotext implementation and disk io. So I guess there is no point to bother with writing custom process launcher.